# Objects are not exported

Tags: export

I try to export a blender file into Maya. I was using FBX and OBJ files but it didn't work as expected.

When I watch at the model in Blender in solid mode some objects are displayed in solid mode, but the rest seems to be in wireframe. The objects in wireframe are not exported. The other Objects work fine.

http://www.filedropper.com/postepack

Has anybody an idea what is wrong with the model and how I can get them into Maya?

Thanks for the Help!!!

Comment: It looks like the objects that displayed as wireframe have no faces.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your file. 
You can see your objects in wireframe only because there are no faces in the object's data, they are only vertices and edges.

Quick solution to solve it would be to

- select the object
- TAB into edit mode
- be in vertex select mode or edge select mode
- select everything and fill with "F"

  This works in most of the cases, sometimes you remain with some unfilled faces that you have to fill manually selecting usually two opposite edges and fill with "F".

I have tried this with a few objects and exported as .obj, opened it with a cad software and the filled objects are exported.